# Problemas em instalar extensões no vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, extensão

Instalei o VSCode e ao tentar instalar uma extensão qualquer o status da mesma não sai de "installing"(Não é gerado nenhum erro ou log).

Já tentei acessar como administrador.
Já alterei a segurança do diretório do vscode para o meu usuário.
Não consigo fazer nada com as extensões.

Alguém já teve este problema?

Comment: Amigo estou de saída, [veja este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41389505/visual-studio-code-extensions-fail-to-install-says-installing-then-gets-stu)

Comment: Olha aqui https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30850 as vezes te ajuda

Comment: Vou ler, obrigado .

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço aos links, 
Consegui resolver o problema do VSCode, consegui identificar o problema pelo "Toggle Shared Process", ele com problema na variavel de ambiente %TEMP% retirei alguns caminhos que não eram mais utilizados, desinstalei o vscode e reinstalei.
Ele acusou a ausência de diretórios na AppData, criei manualmente os mesmos e funcionou o download das extensões.